# Tensorflow: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'constant'

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I have attempted to install `Tensorflow` on Ubuntu 18.04 by following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingVirtualenv) installation guide from the Tensorflow website. However, after importing tensorflow in python/jupyter notebook, none of the functionality appears to be working.

For example if I run:

```
#import tensorflow
import tensorflow as tf

#initialize two constants
x1 = tf.constant([1,2,3,4])
x2 = tf.constant([5,6,7,8])
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'constant'
```

Does anyone know why this attribute is unavailable? on the tensorflow website it should be [still be a fully functional](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant) command.

This is my first time attempting to run tensorflow so any help on the topic would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Haven't you named your file tensorflow.py or your folder /tensorflow?

Comment: the file has a different name but the folder is indeed titled tensorflow (as the tutorial says to do). Do you think this is the problem?

Comment: I think so. I tried to explain the reason in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your folder name to something else except `tensorflow`.

The reason is when you use `import x` python first searches for a folder named `x` and imports `__init__.py` file inside it. In your case you don't have that file with predefined `constant` in it and above that you want the tensorflow itself!

Comment: It didn't seem to work at first but somehow it now does after upgrading tensorflow. thanks!

Comment: @stevezissou I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. After I installed `tensorflow-eigen` the problem is solved.

Comment: Please share the steps for installing tensorflow-eigen